# Fantasy book - Druid novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, love

I'm looking for a book I read ages ago and can only remember part of the story.  I'm sure it was a one off book and not a series.  The main character was a druid apprentice.  A baby girl was left at the druids home and his master left him to help raise her.  Over the years he ended up falling for her and at some point in the story it came to light she was part fey (I think) and her father was

> the master druid.

I really cant remember much more so it's a long shot but if any one recognizes it could they let me know the title and author.

Comment: How long is ages ago? A couple of years, several years, decades? Last Saturday? Do you possibly remember when you read it or when it may have been published, possible something about the cover art? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: No sorry have no idea, Im an avid reader and cannot pin point when I read this book.  I know it was not this year but could of been last year or 5 years ago.  Dont really focus on the book cover so cant remember that either.  Did say it was a long shot and have put all the information I can remember.

Comment: Just a tip, if you haven’t checked the guy, it’s worth glancing at as it has worked wonders with many people that have said they don’t remember any more details

Comment: @Sharon: When someone posts an answer that you believe to be correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 10):

As it happens, I just finished reading those books last night. :-)

You're looking for [The Bredei Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridei_Chronicles) by Juliet Marillier.  A trilogy, not a single book, but your description of the plot is unmistakable.

> The Dark Mirror is the first book of The Bridei Chronicles and tells of Bridei's education under the supervision of Broichan, the king's Druid.  One night Bridei is woken by the moon and outside discovers a baby of the Good Folk, which he takes in and later names Tuala.

Broichan was away when Tuala was found and didn't return until several months later.  He was unhappy about her presence because it might disrupt Bredei's training and because he is afraid that she was put there to interfere with his plans for Bredei's future.

In the third book it is revealed that

> Tuala is in fact Broichan's daughter, although he didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks for that I had thought about her but was so sure it was a single book that had not check.